# Online accounts in 12.10 Facebook not working

Tags: 12.10, chromium, facebook, accounts

I've added my Google, Twitter, and Windows Live accounts without any issues.

However, when I try to add a Facebook account, instead of opening in the system dialogue for online accounts, it opens up a new Window in Chromium which seems a bit odd in the first place. Then, once I authorize Ubuntu to post on my behalf etc., I finish the authorization and Facebook redirects me to a page with just the word "Success" written on it.

Ubuntu still does not show that it is integrated with Facebook, but in my Facebook app settings, I can see clearly that it is authorized.

I should also note that I tried this when Firefox was set as default browser and it did the same thing, so it's not a Chromium issue.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: I have this issue as well, I think that the problem is somewhere in this fact: Other accounts will use the "Online Accounts" browser within the page, though, whenever you try a facebook account, it will open up your default browser instead, and on facebook's side, it all works, but when it sends the confirmation back to your computer, it goes to the broweser instead of the Online Accounts settings page. I would LOVE if somebody knew how to fix this error.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

This problem is believed to have been **resolved** by Facebook as of February 26th.

For details about what caused the problem, see this bug report:

- [Facebook account setup opens in external browser, unusable](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1132030)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. I created a Bug Report https://bugs.launchpad.net/signon-ui/+bug/1132296